# What's the song in Tokyo Ghoul when Tsukiyama tries to stop Kaneki?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

It's also played when Anteiku is on fire and Touka runs to Kaneki. Please help, I've been looking for so long.

Comment: have you tried music recognition apps? What about anime's soundtrack listing?

Comment: @Hakase I have to ask, though - have you ever had success using a music recognition app to identify something off an anime's soundtrack? OPs/EDs generally work pretty well, but I've never had any luck with instrumental pieces.

Comment: @senshin Never tried it, I'm just putting out any available options I can think of. We should probably make a go-to list of things to try.

Comment: Pretty sure it was an acoustic version of Unravel, season 1's OP.

Answer (score 1):

Song ON MY OWN
by Yutaka Yamada